# Swagger Upload FileFilter for 5.0

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, .net-core-3.0

Has anyone been successful in building a file filter for swagger 5.0?

I currently have one for Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 4.0.1: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/4.0.1?_src=template

However since I migrated to net core 3.0, I needed to update my swagger to 5.0. My FileFilter needed to be ammended however I failed to successfully migrate the file filter. Can someone assist please?

Current working SwaggerUploadFileFilter for swagger 4.0.1:

```
public class SwaggerUploadFileFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    private const string formDataMimeType = "multipart/form-data";
    private static readonly string[] formFilePropertyNames =
        typeof(IFormFile).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();

    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var parameters = operation.Parameters;
        if (parameters == null || parameters.Count == 0) return;

        var formFileParameterNames = new List<string>();
        var formFileSubParameterNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (var actionParameter in context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.Parameters)
        {
            var properties =
                actionParameter.ParameterType.GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(IFormFile))
                    .Select(p => p.Name)
                    .ToArray();

            if (properties.Length != 0)
            {
                formFileParameterNames.AddRange(properties);
                formFileSubParameterNames.AddRange(properties);
                continue;
            }

            if (actionParameter.ParameterType != typeof(IFormFile)) continue;
            formFileParameterNames.Add(actionParameter.Name);
        }

        if (!formFileParameterNames.Any()) return;

        var consumes = operation.Consumes;
        consumes.Clear();
        consumes.Add(formDataMimeType);

        foreach (var parameter in parameters.ToArray())
        {
            if (!(parameter is NonBodyParameter) || parameter.In != "formData") continue;

            if (formFileSubParameterNames.Any(p => parameter.Name.StartsWith(p + "."))
                || formFilePropertyNames.Contains(parameter.Name))
                parameters.Remove(parameter);
        }

        foreach (var formFileParameter in formFileParameterNames)
        {
            parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter()
            {
                Name = formFileParameter,
                Type = "file",
                In = "formData"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Attempt using code located online for swagger 5.0:

```
public class SwaggerUploadFileFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (!(operation?.RequestBody?.Content?.Any(x => x.Key.ToLower() == "multipart/form-data") ?? false)) return;

        var uploadFiles = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .Union(context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
            .OfType<SwaggerUploadFile>();

        if (uploadFiles.Count() == 0) return;

        var uploadFile = uploadFiles.First();

        operation.RequestBody.Content["multipart/form-data"].Schema.Properties =
            new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>
            {
                [uploadFile.Parameter] = new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "string",
                    Format = "binary",
                    Description = uploadFile.Description
                }
            };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadFile.Example))
        {
            operation.RequestBody.Content["multipart/form-data"].Schema.Example = new OpenApiString(uploadFile.Example);
            operation.RequestBody.Content["multipart/form-data"].Schema.Description = uploadFile.Example;
        }
    }

    private class SwaggerUploadFile
    {
        public string Parameter { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string Example { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am having trouble making the 5.0 version work with IFormFile.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**5.0-rc4** should work with files without custom operation filter - you just need to remove `[FromForm]` parameter attribute if you have one.

Specified in [GitHub issue discussion](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/193#issuecomment-544516867) and tested myself.

Comment: Seems to do the trick! Thanks very much for spotting this. I appreciate your time writing this answer. Cheers buddy!

Comment: It is working with if the parameter is just IFormFile, but it is not working if its array of IFormFile (IFormFile[]). Did you encounter this issue with an array?

Comment: @dsr301, `IFormFileCollection` should work in this case. You can also check their [tests](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/test/WebSites/Basic/Controllers/FilesController.cs) for more examples.